# Add domain to subfolder with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have many projects like, /var/www/html/test, /var/www/html/test1 etc.
Just wanna to attach my domain to one of these folders.
OS is Debian. Here is my sites-available config

```
server {
    server_name example.me;

    root /var/www/html/example.me;
    index index.html index.php;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

}

I hope any help me with this one thx a lot.

Comment: And it is symlinked to sites-enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will make your `test` folder available at `example.me`.

- Change your `root /var/www/html/example.me;` to `root /var/www/html/test;`
- Copy or symlink your site configuration file to `sites-enabled`
- Restart nginx

Repeat the same process with `test1` in a different site config file and with the correct `server_name` and `root`.